# How do I highlight the current line and the cursor in .vimrc?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I am trying to highlight the current line as well as the cursor position in Vim. Here's my .vimrc:

```
set cursorline
hi CursorLine ctermbg=8 ctermfg=15 "8 = dark gray, 15 = white
hi Cursor ctermbg=15 ctermfg=8
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that the current line background color covers up the cursor background color, so it looks like this:

[image: The current line is highlighted but the cursor is not.]

I can obviously tell where the cursor is because the foreground color is almost black, but when the cursor is on a space or at the beginning/end of a line I have no clue where it is unless I move it.

[image: The cursor is at the end of the line, though you'd never know it.]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to change the color of your cursor line to a color other than the color of your cursor. If you're in a terminal emulator like `st` or `rxvt`, Vim cannot change the color of your cursor; it will always be the color your terminal application decides to make it. Only the graphical version of Vim is able to change the color of your cursor.

You can change your cursor color through your terminal configuration though.

Some `~/.Xdefaults` / `~/.Xresources` examples:

```
XTerm*cursorColor: #FFFFFF
URxvt.cursorColor: white
```

You could also use the Vim command `:set cursorcolumn` to put your cursor in crosshairs.

Comment: `vim` could change the cursor colour, on those terminals like `xterm` that allow you to change it dynamically (`printf '\033]12;#f50\7'` for instance). You can also change it to a blinking block or underline (`\e[1 q` or `\e[3 q`)

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know those escape sequences existed. There's information regarding their use with vim [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor#Changing_the_cursor_color_in_insert_mode).

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want to enter the command each time you start Vim, you have to put the commands in your `.vimrc` file.

```
whereis vim    
*#type in your linux terminal*
```

(you'll have a different location, but your color scheme will be here `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/`.

You can list the existing color schemes with

```
ls /usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/
```

try different color schemes from the listed

```
:colorscheme desert
:colorscheme delek
```

The following command in Vim activates a vertical line at the cursor's location.

```
set cursorcolumn 
hi CursorColumn ctermbg=8
```

to toggle (with the exclamation mark, works with all set-command)

```
set cursorcolumn!
```

for example:

```
set cursorline
set cursorline!

hi CursorLine ctermbg=235
*#defines a gray colour for the horizontal line*
```

Here is a table with xterm colours: [link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Xterm_256color_chart.svg)

Use a number by defining `ctermbg=...`  (... = color number from the table)
You can also try `ctermfg=...`, but it's not worth using it.